# How to access EntityManager from a Dropwizard DAO

Tags: java, dropwizard, entitymanager, unit-of-work

I'm using dropwizard 1.0.3 and I'd like to get my handle on EntityManager. Ultimately what I'm after is CriteriaBuilder but from what I've seen this can only be accessed through EntityManager.

```
public class MyDAO extends AbstractDAO<MyDAO> {
  ...
  method() {
   org.hibernate.Session = currentSession();
   //how to access/create EntityManager here??
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can access the CriteriaBuilder with the currentSession like so:

```
CriteriaBuilder builder = currentSession().getCriteriaBuilder();
```

The AbstractDAO class that you have to extend from gives you access to the currentSession() method which retrieves the current session and allows you to work with the query interface.

Hope this helps.